# Accessing inactive union members

Tags: c, c99, unions

If I have the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
union data_t {
  int8_t sbyte;
  uint8_t ubyte;
  int16_t sint;
  uint16_t uint;
  int32_t slong;
  uint32_t ulong;
  int64_t sint64;
  uint64_t uint64;
  float qsingle;
  double qdouble;
  long double qfloat;
};
union data_t *data;
data = malloc(sizeof(union data_t));
data.uint = 2534;
```

Here, I have assigned the uint16_t type as 42, an I safely access a data type smaller than the one I have assigned to (such as uint8_t), and have it safely typecast (to 230)? This answer ([Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined)) seems to say that it is allowed in C11, but I'm unsure as to whether or not this is legal in C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably compiler specific due to how it arranges the underlying data in the union. Essentially accessing by an 'inactive' member is just *interpreting* the data differently. Interpreting a large int as a smaller one *should* work.

```
[FF|01] < a uint16
```

A `uint8` just reads the first byte of that data:

```
[FF|01]
     ^ read    
^ ignored
```

Interpreting a `float` as an `int` or viceversa is unlikely to work, since the underlying bits won't make sense:

```
[0x1|0xF|0x7FFFFF]
           ^ 23-bit mantissa
      ^ 8-bit exponenent
  ^ sign bit
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. I don't plan to cast to r from floating point numbers, just the integers. If it is compiler-specific as you say, I guess I'll just avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question not well defined in C99 *or* C11. In both standards, §6.2.6.1p7 says:

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the
>   bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that
>   member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

I would certainly see a problem with accessing the `qsingle`, `qdouble` and `qfloat` members after setting a different member. These members might have representations that cause signals such as `SIGFPE` to be raised, and returning from such a signal handler is undefined behaviour.